# Qt update text box from sub method

Tags: c++, qt, do-while

I have a Qt GUI application and a method (not in a class) which contains a while loop. On each iteration of the while loop, I would like to pass the counter to a textbox on the GUI. Is this possible?

Super-simplified code:

image_processor.cpp:

```
void Transition::image_processor (int endindex, int counter) {

    do {
        ...
        counter++; //update textbox with this each iteration
    } while(counter<endindex-1);
}
```

transition.cpp (GUI):

```
Transition::Transition(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Transition)

{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->imageCounter->setText("0");
}

Transition::~Transition()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Transition::on_runButton_clicked()
{
    image_processor(endindex, counter);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think it's possible but you should show your code if you want to receive more complex answer. Do you know the idea of slots and ​​signals in Qt?

Comment: @trivelt I added a simplified version of my code. I have read a little about signals/slots, but I thought it was used more to communicate between GUI elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counter` is int, so you can't set it so simply, you should convert it to `QString`. `QString` has special static method `QString::number()` to do it.

Try this:

```
void Transition::image_processor(int endindex, int counter){

    do {
        ...
        counter++; //update textbox with this each iteration
        ui->imageCounter->setText(QString::number(counter));
    } while(counter<endindex-1)
}
```

And you have mistake:

```
void Transition::on_runButton_clicked()
{
    void Transition::image_processor(endindex, counter);
}
```

should be:

```
void Transition::on_runButton_clicked()
{
    image_processor(endindex, counter);
}
```

you should not use `void`

I think that it was just a typo, but:

```
Transition::Transition(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Transition)   
{
    ui->setupUi(this);//should be
    ui->imageCounter->setText("0");
}//should be
```

As you can see, I added `ui->setupUi(this);` I think again that it is just a typo, but you should add this thing. If you don't do this, your elements from Qt Designer will not be created and you will have error.

Edit:

transition.h (header):

```
//here can be everything, I don't know, you don't post here header but you should add method;
//...
private:
void Transition::image_processor(int endindex, int counter)
```

transition.cpp (GUI):

```
Transition::Transition(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Transition)

{
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->imageCounter->setText("0");
}

Transition::~Transition()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Transition::on_runButton_clicked()
{
    image_processor(endindex, counter);
}

void Transition::image_processor(int endindex, int counter){

    do {
        ...
        counter++; //update textbox with this each iteration
        ui->imageCounter->setText(QString::number(counter));
    } while(counter<endindex-1)
}
```

Comment: I had ui _>setupUI(this), but missed it when posting here. 
    ui->imageCounter->setText(QString::number(counter)); generates two errors for me. invalid use of incomplete type 'class UI::Transition in the method file, and forward declaration of 'class UI::Transition' in the header file

Comment: @user3241316 Why do you create image_processor in separate `image_processor.cpp:`? This error means typo in some names or forgotten include, so see my edit, try to do it in one cpp file.

Comment: @user3241316 also problem can be if you don't include ui_***.h In your case it can be #include `"ui_transition.h"`. My example suggestion about convertation from int to QStrinn is right, now problem with your old code, so I can't said absolutely accurate.

Comment: I was missing "ui_transition.h". It compiles now, but the textbox still isn't changing

Comment: @user3241316 what is textbox , QTextEdit? and it is something impossible. Are you sure that on_runButton_clicked and image_processor called?Add something to this methods to see is this methods work.

Comment: qDebug writes the counter properly.
The text box updates on the very last iteration

Comment: @user3241316 In this case all works normal. while loop can do more then 55000 iterations per second, so it is extremely fast. I think that your numbers very small, so computer operates very fast and you see only last conter

Comment: There is a noticeable (around half a second) time delay between each iteration. I can watch qDebug write each time. During the while loop, the GUI "locks up" and prevents any interaction such as pressing other buttons or closing it. I think this may be the problem, but that might be better suited for a separate question.

Comment: @user3241316 you didn't tell about this before. But anyways it is not surprising because you block your main GUI thread, your GUI doesn't process any events. You should use QThread for this purpose. But you said correct - it is absolutely another question.

Comment: I am not intending to block my main GUI thread, and I just now realized it. I'll make another post about it. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @user3241316 all delays stops full thread(in your case full main GUI thread). If you want do something periodically see QTimer class. QTimer better then loop with delays. QThread should be used when you really really need this.

Comment: If I were to rearrange the code so the while loop is in the on_runButton_clicked() instead of the image_processor method, would this allow the textbox to update each time without needing QThread?
Or is the while loop as a whole going to be its own thread anyways?

Comment: @user3241316 No, on_runButton_clicked() and image_processor works in same thread. I strongly recommend to see QTimer, if you think that it is no what you need, you should use QThread